# Limit as x goes to infinity with logarithm in the exponent

Tags: real-analysis

I try to solve this limit without results, could someone help me?

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \biggl(\frac {e^x-x^2 }{e^x-5x}\biggr)^{\log x} $$

Comment: Do you mean $x^{(2^{\log x})}$ or ${x^2}^{\log x} = x^{2\log x}$? Anyway, I recommend using *L'Hôpital's rule*.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Edit please. What exactly is being raised to the log x power?

Comment: Sorry , I fixed my notation...

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to find the limit of 
$$\log  x\,\bigl(\log(1-x^2\mathrm e^{-x})-\log(1-5x\mathrm e^{-x})\bigr)$$
We'll use an asymptotic expansion. As $x^a\mathrm e^{-x}$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, we have

- $\log(1-x^2\mathrm e^{-x})=-x^2\mathrm e^{-x}+o(x^2\mathrm e^{-x})$
- $\log(1-5x\mathrm e^{-x})=-5x\mathrm e^{-x}+o(x\mathrm e^{-x})$,

so that
\begin{align*}
\log(1-x^2\mathrm e^{-x})-\log(1-5x\mathrm e^{-x})&=(5x-x^2)\mathrm e^{-x}+o(x^2\mathrm e^{-x})+o(x\mathrm e^{-x})\\
&=-x^2\mathrm e^{-x}+o(x^2\mathrm e^{-x})\sim_\infty-x^2\mathrm e^{-x}
\end{align*}
and finally
$$\log x\,\bigl(\log(1-x^2\mathrm e^{-x})-\log(1-5x\mathrm e^{-x})\bigr)\sim_\infty -x^2\mathrm e^{-x}\log x=o(x^3\mathrm e^{-x})\xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{} 0.$$

Comment: ??? The result of the limit must be 1...

Comment: @Tarek: I gave the limit of the log!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we need to evaluate the limit of an expression of type $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}$ then the best approach is to take logarithms.

Thus if $L$ is the desired limit then
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{e^{x} - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x}\right)^{\log x}\right\}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\log\left(\frac{e^{x} - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x}\right)^{\log x}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\log x\log\left(1 + \frac{e^{x} - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x} - 1\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\log x\cdot\dfrac{5x - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{5x - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x}\right)}{\dfrac{5x - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}\cdot\dfrac{5x^{2} - x^{3}}{e^{x} - 5x}\notag\\
&= 0\cdot 0 = 0\notag
\end{align}
Hence $L = 1$. We have used the standard limits $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{e^{x}} = 0\tag{1}$$ which easily leads to $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{5x - x^{2}}{e^{x} - 5x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{5x^{2} - x^{3}}{e^{x} - 5x} = 0\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hand-wavey reasoning that tells you that if there is any justice in this world, then the limit should be $1$. This is not a proof, just strong evidence (it could probably be turned into a proof with the right tools).

First off, it is known that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}x)^x=\frac 1e$. This demonstrates that if the limit of an expression like $(1+\frac{1}{f(x)})^{g(x)}$ is to have a limit other than $0,1$ or $\infty$, then $f$ and $g$ should have the same order.

Your expression can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{(e^x-5x)/(5x-x^2)}\right)^{\log x}
$$and we see that $f$ is (approximately) exponential while $g$ is logarithmic. That's quite a big difference in order, which *strongly* suggests that the limit is indeed $1$.

Comment: Do you mean (1 - 1/f(x))^g(x)? Instead of +.

Comment: @io_cantor In our case, $f$ is negative. It doesn't change anything, since my argument is all about hand waving anyway.

Comment: Why are people down voting?

Comment: @zhw. They probably didn't see that I started this answer by explicitly stating that is hand waving.

Comment: I don't understand . Someone could insert steps?

Comment: @Tarek Where do you want steps inserted? In showing that $\frac{e^x - x^2}{e^x - 5x} = 1-\frac{1}{(e^x - 5x)/(5x - x^2)}$? Because that's the only thing I really do in this answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand because the limit is 1 in this case...

Comment: @Tarek The idea is that if the denominator and the exponent grow at more or less the same pace, then the limit is "interesting" (i.e. not $0,1$ or $\infty$). In this case, however, the denominator grows very quickly while the exponent grows very slowly. That means that what's inside the brackets goes toward $1$ faster than the exponent takes it away from $1$. Again, I have not actually done anything here that _proves_ that they can be compared that way, but once you know what limit to look for, it's not too hard.